# Laravel Cache does not store cache file on production server

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-4

I have a problem with the Laravel Cache system (I use **Laravel 4.1**).

1. On my **local server**, the "**app/storage**" folder where Laravel
   store cache's files is with **755** permission.
2. On my **production server**, the **same folder** has the **same permission**
   code.
3. On my **local server**, when I cache datas using the Laravel's Cache
   Class, **it works**. So If I go within the "**app/storage**" folder, I can see
   the files created.
4. On my **production server**, it doesn't.. **Files aren't created** in
   the cache folder within "**app/storage**" whereas session and views
   folders (present in app/storage) has files stored. I can confirm it
   cause it always go inside my if statement using `has` method even if I put my `$datas` using the `put` method of Cache Class.

**EDIT**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Cache Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default cache "driver" that will be used when
| using the Caching library. Of course, you may use other drivers any
| time you wish. This is the default when another is not specified.
|
| Supported: "file", "database", "apc", "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => 'file',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| File Cache Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "file" cache driver, we need a location where the cache
| files may be stored. A sensible default has been specified, but you
| are free to change it to any other place on disk that you desire.
|
*/

'path' => storage_path(). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cache',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Cache Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" cache driver you may specify the connection
| that should be used to store the cached items. When this option is
| null the default database connection will be utilized for cache.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Cache Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" cache driver we need to know the table that
| should be used to store the cached items. A default table name has
| been provided but you're free to change it however you deem fit.
|
*/

'table' => 'cache',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Memcached Servers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now you may specify an array of your Memcached servers that should be
| used when utilizing the Memcached cache driver. All of the servers
| should contain a value for "host", "port", and "weight" options.
|
*/

'memcached' => array(

    array('host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100),

),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Key Prefix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When utilizing a RAM based store such as APC or Memcached, there might
| be other applications utilizing the same cache. So, we'll specify a
| value to get prefixed to all our keys so we can avoid collisions.
|
*/

'prefix' => 'laravel',
```

Do you have any idea about what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you show us `/app/config/cache.php` or any other cache config file you are using?

Comment: I edit my post to show you my configuration file.

Comment: Is the cache working on the production site? Does it store data?

Comment: Not at all,
when I check if datas have been stored using the if statement after what I put in cache the data, the script still continue to go inside the "if" and if I dump my data cached, it throw me an error saying that the cache key doesn't exist

Comment: Are you possitive the file and folders contained within the storage directory are of the correct permission level.

Comment: Have you created a cache folder in the storage folder with the same  permissions?

Comment: Yes like I said in my answer
Permissions are 755 on my local server and my production server.
And yes the cache folder exist in my storage folder...

Comment: 755 means 7 for the owner, 5 for the group, and 5 for other. Are you sure the user that was used to create the storage folder is the same user that runs apache? Otherwise apache will not have access to the folder.

Comment: Like @dasper said in the last, year old, comment maybe the issue is caused by the owner of the directory being different from that used by the web server. Usually, but not always, the Apache's user is `www-data` or `apache`.

Answer (score 3):

Set the permissions for the folder from 755 to 777 to see if it works. If the cache works now, then you have a permission problem. Set it back to 755 and make sure the user your web server uses is the owner of your folder.